# How to initialize ArrayList<Double> in one line from a list of mixed integer and float?

Tags: java

I have following code running smoothly and print out [1,2,3,4,5] successfully.

```
import static java.util.Arrays.asList;

public class JavaApplication2 {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> Foo()
    {       
       return new ArrayList<>(asList(1,2,3,4,5));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Foo());
    }    
}
```

However, if I change the return type be

```
ArrayList<Double>,
```

then I have "incompatible types" compiling error.

**The question:** How can I write the function body (it would be great if done in one line) by given ONLY the following resources?

- return type:

  ```
  ArrayList<Double>
  ```
- 1.0, 2, 3.1, 4, 5

Note: I'm writing a program to generate code from the given list literal text and **I can NOT tokenize the comma separated value** and the value could be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 or a mix of them.

```
public class JavaApplication2 {
    public static ArrayList<Double> Foo()
    {
        //HOW TO WRITE THIS FUNCTION BODY?       
        1.0, 2, 3.1, 4, 5
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Foo());
    }    
}
```

I'm expecting the program print:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.1, 4.0, 5.0]
```

Comment: Changing the return type to: public static ArrayList<Number> Foo() will do the trick and it will print out: [1.0, 2, 3.1, 4, 5]. All good.

Comment: In the "working" example you mean `Arrays.asList(...)`

Comment: @JimGarrison actually I have: import static java.util.Arrays.asList;  Corrected in the post

Comment: That kind of import static is a bad idea.  It just confuses future readers, who will first look for a local method called `asList()`.  Don't do it except with constants.

Comment: @JimGarrison That's a matter of opinion. Personally, I think static method imports are ok if the method names are descriptive enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a `DoubleStream`:

```
public static ArrayList<Double> Foo() {
    return DoubleStream.of(1.0, 2, 3.1, 4, 5)
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! It just looks a little bit scary (too long).